# How to sum the sql statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT sum(l.interestrt*d.bidspotrate) AS [Interest Rate in MYR],
       SUM (l.interestsprd * d.bidspotrate), sum(l.penaltyrt*d.bidspotrate)
FROM loan l,
     danadb d
```

How to sum all of the sql statements from above? I have no idea how to sum all from different column.
Thank you.

Comment: You can find more than a dozen solution online for this question.

Comment: Have you thought of simply adding the values?

Comment: `+` A Magic operator that does it :-)

Comment: you do have a Cartesian join happening which means you will be getting way way more rows then you are likely intending and the SUM of multiplied rates... not sure this is making since for any business use case you may want to put together some example data and desired result and ask for help that way so that your intention is more clear.

Comment: when I run the query, it will shows 3 different columns . So, now , I want the sum value of three columns. is it possible ?

Comment: Syntax error. Why that leading `(`?

Comment: @jarlh the symbol ( on the left, first line is typo. I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT SUM (L.INTERESTRT * D.BIDSPOTRATE) AS "Interest Rate in MYR",
       SUM (L.INTERESTSPRD * D.BIDSPOTRATE),
       SUM (L.PENALTYRT * D.BIDSPOTRATE)
  FROM LOAN L CROSS JOIN DANADB D
```

Comment: Thank you for answering :), but the query you just gave is produce same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

@Mir try this

```
(select sum(l.interestrt*d.bidspotrate) as 'Val1', 
   SUM (l.interestsprd * d.bidspotrate) as 'Val2', 
   sum(l.penaltyrt*d.bidspotrate) as 'Val3' ,
   (SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2) + SUM(Val3)) as 'Total'
from loan l inner join  danadb d on l.someid = d.someid
```

Comment: Thank you for answering :) , but i got error while running your query, says that on line 4 , invalid column name for val1,val2 and val3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will give you the output what you expect:

```
select (one+two+three) as [Interest Rate in MYR] from
(select sum(l.interestrt*d.bidspotrate) as [one] 
   SUM (l.interestsprd * d.bidspotrate) as [two], 
   sum(l.penaltyrt*d.bidspotrate) as [three]
from loan l,danadb d) t
```

OR

```
select (sum(l.interestrt*d.bidspotrate)+ 
    SUM (l.interestsprd * d.bidspotrate)+ 
    sum(l.penaltyrt*d.bidspotrate)) as [Interest Rate in MYR]
from loan l,danadb d
```

Note: you can get rid from these old fashioned join and implement one with common columns from the tables as:

```
FROM loan l
INNER JOIN danadb d ON d.<id> = l.<id>
```

Comment: I got the result . Thank you so much :) .  Have a nice day :D

Comment: Thank you again . The second query also produce the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add them?

```
SELECT   SUM (L.INTERESTRT * D.BIDSPOTRATE)
       + SUM (L.INTERESTSPRD * D.BIDSPOTRATE)
       + SUM (L.PENALTYRT * D.BIDSPOTRATE)
          AS "Interest Rate in MYR"
  FROM LOAN L CROSS JOIN DANADB D
```

Comment: Oh yes, I did not think about it at all . The query produce the result that i want . Thank you again :)